# SSRS Report in C# console app doesn't fill printed page

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Below is code for a VS2015 C# console app where I printing an 8.5x14 SSRS report (no data connection). When I print the report from Report Builder, it renders correctly. When I print it from my console app, the report doesn't fill the page. I am rendering the report to a stream where I set the size to 8.5x14, then printing it, setting the document size to 8.5x14. Not sure what else I need to do to get it to fit.

If anyone would take a look and offer advise, I would be very grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
namespace SULabelPrinting
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int m_currentPageIndex;
        private static IList<Stream> m_streams;
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
                report.ReportPath = @"..\..\Test.rdl";
                Export(report);
                Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        // Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to
        //    save an image for each page of the report.
        private static Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_streams.Add(stream);
            return stream;
        }

        // Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
        private static void Export(LocalReport report)
        {
            string deviceInfo =
              @"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>14in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>.1in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>.1in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>.1in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>.1in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
               out warnings);
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Position = 0;
        }

        // Handler for PrintPageEvents
        private static void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            Metafile pageImage = new
               Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

            // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                ev.PageBounds.Left - (int) ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                ev.PageBounds.Top - (int) ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                ev.PageBounds.Width,
                ev.PageBounds.Height);

            // Draw a white background for the report
            ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            // Draw the report content
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

            // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
            m_currentPageIndex++;
            ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
        }

        private static void Print()
        {
            if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("No stream to print.");

            PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Legal", 850, 1400);
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPageHandler);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (m_streams != null)
            {
                foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                    stream.Close();
                m_streams = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it helps, below is a link to the project. 
[SULabelPrinting.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhe3daqi58zhq7c/SULabelPrinting.zip?dl=0)

Thanks,
Steve.

Comment: Paste your code in your question or provide a screenshot. Dont link to code on DropBox....

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I edited the original post to include the code. The RDL file is nothing special. Just an 8.5 x 14 landscape report, with no data connection.

Comment: Could it be your printer margins? When you say it doesn't fill the page do you mean it is off by a little or a lot?

Comment: The top and left margins look good. The right side of the document only extends approximately 11 inches instead of 14. And the bottom doesn't extend to the bottom of the page. The printout looks proportionate.